# Sending emails from IBM BPM on Cloud?

Tags: smtp, ibm-bpm

If I run IBM BPM within my own enterprise, I can configure BPM to use my own SMTP server within my enterprise to send emails.  However, when I run IBM BPM on Cloud I seem to have a puzzle/problem.  To what SMTP server should I direct my requests to transmit emails?

I can't target my internal SMTP server because it is internal and there is no network path from BPM on Cloud to my internal corporate SMTP server.  Unfortunately, even if there was a path, the IBM supplied SMTP email service within IBM BPM doesn't support SMTP credentials and I obviously can't expose an un-authenticated SMTP relay to the Internet from within my company.

Has anyone successfully achieved sending emails from a BPM process hosted by IBM BPM on Cloud and, if so, what recipe was used to transmit the emails?

Comment: Will an online SMTP relay work ? Something like this :https://www.mailjet.com/feature/smtp-relay/ , is it for notifications in the process or for notifications in the system (New task assigned and so forth) ?

Comment: The puzzle I was facing was to transmit an email to an "external customer".  For example, imagine a process instance that is processing an insurance claim.  When the process outcome is finalized, I want to email the customer to inform them of information relating to their claim.  Thus I must send an email over the Internet.  The recipient is not a participant in the mechanics of the process.  Currently we have written our own Java code that uses JavaMail that uses SSL/TLS and security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM BPM  doesn't support SMTP credentials. I made a work around solution that I made a Java code module for sending email and I attached to my BPM.
I made a lot of searches before for this problem but I didn't find any other solution for this problem.